# How to allow user to input a word like "end" to finish their entry of data values

Tags: python

I am just beginning programming in python and I have to complete a program that allows a user to input as many data values as they want and when they are done, they must type "end". I want to create a list from the inputted values but when the word "end" is inputted, I get a value error that says, could not convert string to float: 'end'. Could someone please explain why this is and how to fix this error?

This is my program so far:

```
data_list=[]
end=0
print("Enter data points and type 'end' to finish the entry.")
#loop repeats continuously
while(end==0):
  data=float(input("Value of data point:"))
  data_list.append(float(data))
  if data=='end':
    end=1
    break
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and the full error

Comment: Please, give us a sample of your code, then we can help you! Read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input()
b = []
while a != 'end':
    b.append(float(a))
    a = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel argument.

This creates an iterator that calls `input` until `'end'` is provided by the user. In particular, this sentinel value is not yielded by the iterator.

```
lst = [float(x) for x in iter(input, 'end')]

print(lst)
```

### Example

```
1.0
2.5
5.6
end
[1.0, 2.5, 5.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to include a code sample when posting a question, since it makes it easier for people to help!

That being said, it seems as though you are trying to convert the input to a float using: `float(input_variable)`. This will throw an error when input_variable isn't a string.

One workaround for this would be to do:

```
try:
   input_variable = float(input_variable)
except ValueError:
   if input_variable == 'end':
      return your_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the error to break the loop: I hope this is useful for you! :)

```
list = []
print("Enter data points and type 'end' to finish the entry.")
while True:
    try:
        data = float(input("Value of data point:"))
        list.append(data)
    except:
        ValueError
        data = str(data)
        if "end" in data:
            break
```